# MYSQL Duplicate Data and Show Only One Data

Tags: mysql

I have data like this

```
emp_id|   name  |  log                 |
16646 | bella   |  2023-01-30 07:28:54 | 
9050  | mark    |  2023-01-30 07:22:12 |
8612  | nandya  |  2023-01-30 07:20:35 |
7965  | arya    |  2023-01-30 06:21:39 |
7965  | arya    |  2023-01-30 06:21:40 |
```

My query

```
SELECT h.emp_id, p.name, h.log
FROM presence.history h
JOIN employee p on p.emp_id = h.emp_id 
and h.log >= '2023-01-30 05:00:00' and h.log <= '2023-01-30 07:45:00'
```

I want the duplicate data only show one data and for the 'log' field show the early data.

the result I expected

```
emp_id|   name  |  log                 |
16646 | bella   |  2023-01-30 07:28:54 | 
9050  | mark    |  2023-01-30 07:22:12 |
8612  | nandya  |  2023-01-30 07:20:35 |
7965  | arya    |  2023-01-30 06:21:39 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT emp_id, name, MIN(log) as log
FROM table_name
GROUP BY emp_id, name;